# What is a GitLab instance URL, and how can I get it?

Tags: gitlab

I have tried searching for it everywhere, but I can’t find anything.

It would be really awesome if someone could define it straight out of the box.

I don’t know what an instance of GitLab URL is. I’m asking if someone could clarify what it is, and where can I get it. I am currently trying to add it in [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) extension *[GitLab Workflow](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gitlab.gitlab-workflow)*. The extension is asking for my GitLab instance URL, and I don’t know where to get it.

Comment: please clarify your question. Are you installing a self-managed version and looking for it after install? Or something else...?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The instance URL of any GitLab install is basically the link to the GitLab you're trying to connect to.

For example, if your project is hosted on `gitlab.example.com/yourname/yourproject` then for the instance URL enter `https://gitlab.example.com`.

Another example, if your project is hosted on `gitlab.com/username/project` then the instance URL is `https://gitlab.com`. Though note that in the VS Code extension specifically, [gitlab.com is the default](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitLab.gitlab-workflow#extension-settings) so you can leave it blank in this case.

Comment: So simple, thank you 

Comment: The instance URL is the schema and the host of your gitlab installation, i.e. https://gitlab.com not just gitlab.com.
See the GitLab Workflow docs: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitLab.gitlab-workflow#extension-settings

Comment: true, Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the answer to be more explicit

Comment: This answer is not so explicit. If you do not have any domain between `gitlab` and `.com`, then the instance is simply `gitlab.com`

Comment: I've added another example specifically regarding `gitlab.com`. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for edit @Arty-chan. Now, it looks better.

Comment: Thanks m8,I was struggling with the Gitlab Workflow extension for vscode

Comment: forthe current version of vscode at least, do CTRL + SHIFT + P, select GitLab: Add Account to VScode, leave the default gitlab.com that is in there and press enter, then copy your access token and press enter .

Answer (score 2):

I have gone through the same problem. I first couldn't successfully verify my ssh connection since i though my gitlab instance was the link to my personal repository. Which is not the case.

"your gitlab instance" in simple word is the gitlab service your are using. Which most of the time is `git@gitlab.com`. Hence, to verify your ssh connection to gitlab repository after ssh configuration simply using the gitlab command :
`ssh -T git@gitlab.com`

Answer (score 0):

If your username is stack-overflow then your GitLab instance URL would be **stack-overflow@gitlab.com**

So to add your SSH Key

`ssh -T stack-overflow@gitlab.com`

Answer (score -1):

I didn't find the accepted answer satisfying, so here is my take.

As far as the [page about SSH configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/index.html#verify-that-you-can-connect) is concerned, if your login is, say, `Maverick`, then the GitLab instance URL is `Maverick@gitlab.com`. Apparently, the instance URL shows up during a keyboard-interactive login:

```
Username for 'https://gitlab.com': TypeYourNick
Password for 'https://TypeYourNick@gitlab.com':
```

The [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_one.html) presents this information rather vaguely... (it didn't help me at all)

Comment: You're wrong. The page you reference makes it clear that the username and `@` character are not part of the instance URL.