# What is url and clone_url suppose to be in this AWS example?

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration, docker-machine

I'm setting up my own AWS EC2 GitLab-Runner for the first time.

This is for a unity app. I have a server on an EC2 instance and client being downloaded from the S3 bucket.

I am following the information located [here](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/43e96ac6-6d4f-4d99-af97-3ac2a5987391/en-US/020-build-farms/060-labs-unity-mac/060-setup-gitlab/020-setup-linux-spot-build-agent). There's a section that asks for the clone_url and url. What URL are these support to be exactly? Which server? I am using this for CI/CD.

Here's the example:

```
executor = "docker+machine"
limit = 1
  IdleCount = 1
  [runners.docker]
    image = "alpine"
    privileged = true
    disable_cache = true
  [runners.cache]
    Type = "s3"
    Shared = true
    [runners.cache.s3]
      ServerAddress = "s3.amazonaws.com"
      BucketName = "CI_Output_test"
      BucketLocation = "ca-central-1b"
  [runners.machine]
    IdleCount = 1
    clone_url = "{Your server URL}"
    url = "{Your server URL}"
    IdleTime = 1800
    MaxBuilds = 100
    MachineDriver = "amazonec2"
    MachineName = "gitlab-docker-machine-%s"
    MachineOptions = [
      "amazonec2-access-key=AKIARKHQWANMXAYATCNY",
      "amazonec2-secret-key=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",
      "amazonec2-region=ca-central-1",
      "amazonec2-vpc-id=vpc-81395de9",
      "amazonec2-ssh-user=ubuntu",
      "amazonec2-zone=b",
      "amazonec2-root-size=32",
      "amazonec2-subnet-id=subnet-8ff553f5",
      "amazonec2-use-private-address",
      "amazonec2-tags=runner-manager-name,gitlab-aws-autoscaler,gitlab,true,  gitlab-runner-autoscale,true",
      "amazonec2-security-group=sg-07473b8e1309d49cd",
      "amazonec2-request-spot-instance=true",
      "amazonec2-iam-instance-profile=MacRunnerSSMInstance",
      "amazonec2-instance-type=c5.4xlarge"
    ]
    [[runners.machine.autoscaling]]
      Periods = ["* * 9-17 * * mon-fri "]
      IdleCount = 1
      IdleTime = 3600
      Timezone = "UTC"
    [[runners.machine.autoscaling]]
      Periods = [" * * * * sat,sun *"]
      IdleCount = 1
      IdleTime = 60
      Timezone = "UTC"
```

Comment: Looks like they're both supposed to be populated with Server URL and that comes from "Settings" -> CI/CD -> Expand "Runners" in the GitLab web UI for your repo.

Comment: @jarmod so it's pretty much the same URL as the runner registration which is https://gitlab.com/ for the Gitlab folks? Thank you

Comment: For this workshop, you need to use a GitLab instance. You can install it on an EC2 instance (GitLab AMI is an another solution  - https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-w6ykryurkesjq) or use the SAAS solution, which is free for 30 days (https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/). You should set your GitLab instance URL to the `url` and `clone_url` variables.

Comment: @suMmGuy Your GitLab instance's URL can't be gitlab.com

Comment: @Zili does it mean: https://gitlab.com/group/project.git ? The following answer is confusing this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58236175/what-is-a-gitlab-instance-url-and-how-can-i-get-it

Comment: @suMmGuy Where is your GitLab located? How do you access it?

Comment: @Zili The repo is in a private group gitlab. It's located at https://gitlab.com/group/voila_ci_test/-/tree/main and I clone it using https://gitlab.com/group/voila_ci_test.git or git@gitlab.com:group/voila_ci_test.git